# Ошибка при загрузке js, Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток.
Пытаюсь воспользоваться скриптом из js файла, но выдается ошибка

```
 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
    (anonymous) @   bootstrap.min.js:6
```

что находится в html

```
<script src="/js/admin.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

срипты и линки, взяты с bootstrap-а, т.к использую их шаблон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам Twitter Bootstrap не зависит от jQuery.

Если вы используете только часть CSS, вам не понадобится jQuery.

Если вы используете Javascript-плагины, вам нужен jQuery, поскольку они являются jQuery-плагинами.

```
........
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
........
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ссылку и помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так нормально говорит что вам необходимо сделать, `js` у бутстрапа работает на `jquery`, Сделайте так.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/admin.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
```